# How do I put these 2 dates next to each other?

Tags: javascript

Ok, what i want to do is to to put the month and day next to each other. 
So, the variables **m** and **dd**

```
   var meps = 14;
    var boot = 15;
    var d = new Date('December 16, 2014');
    var m = d.getMonth();
    var dd = d.getDate();

    document.getElementById('days').innerHTML = m;
```

But, when I do m + dd, it **adds** them, instead of sticking them right next to each other.

How could I do this??

Comment: document.getElementById('days').innerHTML = m + "" + dd;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply use the toString method

```
document.getElementById('days').innerHTML = m.toString() + dd.toString();
```

Fiddle Here:
http://jsfiddle.net/zvw5L3uq/

Answer (score 1):

How about concatenating a space in there as well.

```
m + " " + dd;
```